# Visual Studio 2015 (with Update 3) Professional Fatal Error in Installing Core Features

Tags: visual-studio-2015, fatal-error

During the installation of Visual Studio 2015 I encountered a fatal error upon attempting to install core features.  Below are the error statements from my log file:

[43F0:3B34][2018-05-30T14:19:46]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[43F0:3B34][2018-05-30T14:19:46]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[437C:3DD4][2018-05-30T14:19:46]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.

I have searched for a solution and tried a few that I've found, such as going into ProgramData and renaming Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18 to ...\S-1-5-18_old and running the installer as admin, but this did not work.

I need this compiler for Simulink Realtime for my research.

I already have Visual Studio 2017 Community, but the general consensus seems to be that different versions don't interfere.

If more information is needed, please let me know and I can provide it.  I would appreciate any help you can provide me with.

Comment: Update: Tried going to Programs and Features in the Control Panel and then repairing the installer.  Same errors.  Some new ones seem to have appeared:


[36CC:2E84][2018-05-30T15:26:13]e000: Error 0x80070666: Process returned error: 0x666
[36CC:2E84][2018-05-30T15:26:13]e000: Error 0x80070666: Failed to execute EXE package.
[04B8:4308][2018-05-30T15:26:13]e000: Error 0x80070666: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.

Comment: Also, it tells me the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 (x64 and x86) is already installed, but I don't see it in Programs and Features although I see other Redistributable Files.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a file is corrupted or at least Windows thinks it is.
You should try to absolutely uninstall Visual Studio with all of its doomed components.
Then install again.

Problem is that in most of cases uninstall also can't be completed because that corrupted file bloks uninstallation ad installer drop an error.

No problemo. In this case you should to use the magnificent *Visual Studio Uninstaller*
This application remove whole Visual Studio completely, totally and entirely.

Download from here: https://github.com/microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

After that you are able to install Visual Studio whitout any problem.

(You need .net framework 4.x installed on your machine to use *Visual Studio Uninstaller*)